# Write .rpt file using Python

Tags: python

As I know Pandas can read .RPT file quite easily:

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.read_csv('sample.rpt', delimiter = '|')
```

But how can we write a data frame to .RPT file using Python?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: As the function name implies, you are reading a `csv` file, not a `rpt` file. I've posted an answer but I think you should change your file extension names.

Comment: You would not be able to open a RPT file from Crystal Reports using *pandas*. You appear to have a valid CSV file with a dubious extension

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation; https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
df.to_csv('sample.rpt', delimiter='|')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write pandas dataframe to .rpt file

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "John Smith"],
    "Age": [30, 25, 40],
    "Occupation": ["Engineer", "Teacher", "Doctor"]
})

with open("df.rpt", "w") as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

The output file

```
Name,Age,Occupation
John Doe,30,Engineer
Jane Doe,25,Teacher
John Smith,40,Doctor
```